# Ionic Appflow deploy failing with api access error

Tags: ionic-framework, fastlane

My Appflow deployment to the Playstore keeps failing with this error:

Google Api Error: Invalid request - Access Not Configured. Google Play Developer API has not been used in project before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/androidpublisher.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxx then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

But the Service Account is enabled and linked to the Play Store account with Release Manager perms, and is even tracking requests when I try to do a build

Comment: I have the exact same issue on my side. Cannot figure out why so far...

Comment: Me too on flutter